# No module named 'matplotlib' Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am very new to programming so bear with me.
I am trying to import matplotlib . I have matplotlib already on my computer. When I

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstalled matplot lib using pip and pip3 multiple times. When I uninstall I get this and then reinstall I get this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\...
```

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling python but that doesn't seem to do anything.
What can I do to fix this? I am using the most recent version of Python.

Comment: can you please specify your environment, whether linux  or mac or any other ?

Comment: @kirtipurohit Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple python editors, make sure you installed `matplotlib` with the `pip.exe` from the python editor you are trying to import `matplotlib.pyplot` in.

Make the `pip.exe` you are using in a folder called Scripts is in the folder that contains to python editor of interest.

For example, the `pip.exe` from `Pycharm` could be `'C:\Users\User\jetbrains\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts'`, while the `pip.exe` from `spyder` could be `'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts'`.

Comment: Make the `pip` is in a folder called `Scripts` that is in the folder that contains to python editor of interest.

Comment: @MartinChapman For example, the `pip.exe` from `Pycharm` could be `'C:\Users\User\jetbrains\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts'`, while the `pip.exe` from `spyder` could be `'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts'`.

Comment: This sort of problem is why I recommend learning how to interact with python via a command line interface (and a simple text editor) before graduating to an IDE. IDE's are very helpful, but they do hide some of the important background information from you.

Comment: you can easily find where your python is by calling `import sys;print(sys.executable)`, and you can find where pip is by opening up cmd (not powershell) and calling `where pip`

Comment: @Aaron ok so when I called where pip it is in C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe but there is also pip in scripts as Ann Zen suggested

Comment: @MartinChapman What is the python editor you are using?

Comment: @AnnZen This PC/ OS (C:) / Program Files / JetBrains / Pycharm Community Edition

Comment: @AnnZen oh so could I move the matplotlib folder to there? I see where the matplotlib folder is. edit* that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MartinChapman Search for `pip.exe` in the `JetBrains` folder. Copy the path of it. In your `cmd`, enter `cd your_path`, then enter `pip install matplotlib`.

Comment: @AnnZen I can actually just install matplotlib through pycharm itself without using the cmd prompt. Thank you for your help.